# Combining polygon and raster using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon, merge, combine

How do I combine the raster data and county outline polygon so that only the elevation data within the county boundaries is displayed?

[image: raster and polygon]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You can clip your raster to the polygon using the [Clip tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/clip.htm). Make sure you select "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry" otherwise the raster will only be clipped to the extent of the feature class, not the polygon boundary.